# Не поучается изменить движение объекта касанием об другой объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня такая идея при касании определённого объекта пушка изменяет движение в другую сторону я сделал вроде всё правильно, но почему то всё равно не работает вот код:

```cs
public class gunMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool rightMove = true;

    public float speed;

    public GameObject rightWall;

    
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == ("rigthWall"))
        {
            rightMove = false;
        }
        
        if (other.gameObject.tag == ("leftWall"))
                {
            rightMove = true;
        }
        
    } 
    void Update()
    {
        if(rightMove == true)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed);
        }
        if(rightMove == false)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, ошибка может быть здесь `rigthWall`, т.к. правый - right. Во-вторых, добавьте в OnTriggerEnter принты, чтобы понять, где у вас недорабатывает код. Обратите внимание на то, что, чтобы работал OnTriggerEnter2D нужно, чтобы на обоих объектах висели: BoxCollider2D, хотя бы на одном Rigidbody2D,  1 (не 0, не 2) должен быть триггером

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213975/Не-меняется-bool-значение-при-достижении-y-позиции/1214047#1214047